# Can someone give me info on how to numerate comment rows?

Tags: c, visual-c++-6

So, here is my problem. I need to write a program that numerates comment rows in a text file. I searched everywhere, but i can't find answers to the question how to do it.Here is an example text file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i; /* declare i as an integer */

    for(i=0;i<=10000;i=i+1)
    {
        printf("%d\t",i); /* print the value of i */
    }
    return(0);
}
```

So, i need to put a number in front of the rows with comments.

Comment: Tagging your question with "visual-studio" is rather useless. Please change the tag to the language you are using - you can use up to 5 tags - please do so.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create a parser that will look  through your code to find special text pattern. The concept is simple:

1. You go through the file from the begining until you find the comment
2. You look for the first New Line Feed character
3. You insert your number right after

There are several ways to do it. You could manually look character by character but you could also use little more sophisticated method such as regular expressions.

http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html